# How to store part of the matched string from vim regex into a variable?

Tags: vim, vi

I am writing a vim function which lists all the "classes" defined in a file. Here is the script

```
function! My_func()
  let l:line_no = 1
  let l:line = ""
  let l:class_name = ""

  while l:line_no <= line("$")

    let l:line = getline(l:line_no)

    if l:line =~ 'class\s\+\(\S\+\)'
      let l:class_name = \1 " This does not work.
    endif

    let l:line_no += 1

  endwhile
endfunction
```

I have a little bit of Perl background and in perl you can store part of the matched regex in special variables such as $1 $2 etc. Do we have something equivalent in vimrc?

I could achieve the same by using matchstr function and then parsing it char by char, however I would like to know if there is a better way of doing it.

Thanks

Comment: `:h matchlist()`